# Error CS0246 appears in unity when no errors appear on VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use a variable from another file and this is what I have currently come up with:

File 1:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

(More Code)

#region MyVars

    namespace MyVars
{
    public class MyVarsClass
    {
        public int x = 2;
    }
}
#endregion
```

File 2:

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using MyVars;




public class AppearDisappear : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int x;
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create an instance of MyClass
        MyVarsClass myInstance = new MyVarsClass();

        // Access the variable from MyClass       
        x = myInstance.x;
    }
 (More Code)

}
```

The assignment of x as 2 is not my main goal, just there for test purposes, it will be later changed from actions within the game. Of course there is more code in both files but it isn't relevant to the problem.

No errors appeared in the compiler so I guessed it would work but when I open unity
`"Assets\ModularFirstPersonController\FirstPersonController\Appear Disapear.cs(10,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace "MyVars" could not be found(are you using a directive or assembly reference?)"` 
appeared, and it asked me to resolve all compiler errors before executing the game, when there weren't any errors in the compiler...

I suppose I have to reference File 1 in File 2, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how...

I found this in learn.microsoft.com but the compiler doesn't seem to be recognizing it
`<Reference Include="filename" />`

I am using Unity 2022.3.14f1

Comment: well there are so many questions about the above code - especially the static void main.. but.. did you put asmdefs in your project?

Comment: Unity is always right .. it is Unity compiling your code .. whether your IDE correctly catches the issue as well is up to your configuration ;) ... So there is two issues: your actual issue Unity is flagging.. and then the issue that your IDE doesn't capture that correctly ;) are you working with [Assembly Definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) in your project ..?

Comment: Also a possibility: The file containing the `MyVars` and your class itself has compiler errors and thus has not been fully compiled yet so the other one doesn't know it yet => I would first comment out your new class and see if there are any other issues first

Comment: Finally ... if you have a `static void Main()` in any of your Unity classes you are doing something very wrong to begin with ....

Comment: @derHugo and @BugFinder, the `static void Main()` is only in that part of the code in order for me to transfer the variable from the other file (I found it that way online and I copied it). I don't have much experience neither do I know the more advanced coding principles like classes, and it's the first time I work in unity, so it's a lot of trial and error. I doubt that VS would fail to detect a compiler error, but I am not sure  I have configured the assembly stuff you mentioned, so I will research that.

Comment: @derHugo I commented out the class and unity runs fine, no errors in the compiler or in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer came from @derHugo in a comment, the problem was Assembly Definitions. I am not sure if I did it the best way but this problem can by solved like this:

1. Make File2 a child by creating a folder and placing it in there.
2. Create an Assembly Definition in the Parent folder
3. Create an Assembly Definition Reference in the Child folder
4. Select the Assembly Definition you created in the parent folder in the Parent folder at the "Assembly Definition" input of the Assembly Definition Reference file.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people